# How can I make gson exclude my object's superclass?

Tags: java, gson

Im trying to serialize/deserialize using Gson. I don't want the super class (which is abstract) to be considered, the problem is that I don't have access to the super class code.

I've tried with an `ExclusionStrategy` but it didn't work.

```
private class SuperClassExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return clazz.equals(SuperClass.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

How can I solve this?

**Edit:**

I need the fields in the superclass to be ignored, this is because I am getting this error: `MyClass declares multiple JSON fields named`.
I can not change the conflicting fields name.

**Solution:**

Solved with the following strategy:

```
private static class SuperClassExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

  public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
   return false;
  }

  public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
   return field.getDeclaringClass().equals(MySuperClass.class) && field.getName()
    .equals("id");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [Gson documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html)

> Exclude fields and objects based on a particular class type:

```
private static class SpecificClassExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
    private final Class<?> excludedThisClass;

    public SpecificClassExclusionStrategy(Class<?> excludedThisClass) {
        this.excludedThisClass = excludedThisClass;
    }

    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return excludedThisClass.equals(clazz);
   }

   public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return excludedThisClass.equals(f.getDeclaringClass()());
   }
}
```

Comment: `getDeclaringClass` does the job not `getDeclaredClass`

Comment: @RenéLink No, the OP wanted to exclude all fields of a particular class, not fields being of some type. That is (e.g class Clazz { String f;}) if all fields of class Clazz are to be excluded, then we should use "f.getDeclaringClass() == Clazz.class", not "f.getDeclaredClass() == String.class".

Comment: Say that there is a superclass `Mammal` and a subclass `Human`. Whenever `Mammal` is passed directly to GSON, I would like it to be serialized. However, whenever GSON comes across a `Human` object, I only want GSON to serialize the `Human`-specific fields and not the fields inherited from `Mammal`. Can an `ExclusionStrategy` handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
    builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
```

Then explicitly expose only the fields you want exposed.